# Is there a way to get a confirmation email with a PDF file of a form to the person who completes the form?

Tags: cognito-forms

My employees will be submitting forms but they may also need to print out the form that they complete.

How can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

If you are on a paid plan with Cognito Forms then you can include a PDF in both the confirmation email and the notification email. Both can be set up on the Build page under 'Submission Settings'.

Once you have selected the email you want to update, a dialog box will open. To add a PDF you will want to enable 'Documents' then select the template to use. The two that are set up are our default templates. The first is the simple version of the form, showing the label and the response or selection. The second shows an 'edit' view of the form displaying boxes around text fields, and radio buttons for Choice fields. You can learn more about this in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/13/building-forms/confirmation-emails).